# Ensure that ASCII escape sequences (e.g. color code) are correctly encoded while loading json

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, ascii

I have a JSON file with weather icons in ascii style. I add some color to the characters.

```
{
  "cloudy": "             \n\\033[38;5;250m     .--.    \\033[0m\n\\033[38;5;250m  .-(    ).  \\033[0m\n\\033[38;5;250m (___.__)__) \\033[0m\n             "
}
```

Now I want to load the colored icons in Python with this snippet:

```
import json

with open('icon.json') as file:
    jsonObject = json.load(file)
    file.close()

print(jsonObject['cloudy'])
```

And I get this

```
\033[38;5;250m     .--.    \033[0m
\033[38;5;250m  .-(    ).  \033[0m
\033[38;5;250m (___.__)__) \033[0m
```

If I print the cloudy value, directly I get the colored result, here is the snippet if you want to reproduce it.

```
print("""                        
            \033[38;5;250m     .--.    \033[0m
            \033[38;5;250m  .-(    ).  \033[0m
            \033[38;5;250m (___.__)__) \033[0m
                         """)
```

It seems that `json.loads()` can't interpret the ASCII escape sequence correctly.
Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `print(jsonObject['cloudy'].encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode( 'unicode_escape'))`.

Comment: @JosefZ great that worked. Thank you! May I ask you to write this as an answer and I will mark it as solution.